# Call to undefined function stats_standard_deviation()

Tags: php, wamp, pecl, standard-deviation

My PHP version is `5.4.16`

I found `php_stats` (and `php_http`) here:

> http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/

Got this version: `php_stats-1.0.3-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip`

*(Yes I have 32bit)*

- Copied `php_stats.dll` to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\ext`
- Add `extension=php_stats.dll` (and `extension=php_http.dll`) to `php.ini` (located in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin`)
- exit wamp, start wamp, restart all services

  wamp -> php -> php extensions -> php_stats is checked (and php_http)

But I still get the same error (see title). How can I solve this?

> **Call to undefined function stats_standard_deviation() php pecl stats wamp windows 7**

Comment: The extension must match the PHP version. You downloaded an extension for PHP 5.6, but your PHP version is 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another package here:

> http://pecl.php.net/package/stats/1.0.3/windows

this one is working